# Web3js - Pressing a button and trigger function

Tags: javascript, jquery, web3js

I am using the [web3js library](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js) in my frontend to connect with my smart contract backend

See below my code:

```
App = {
  web3Provider: null,
  contracts: {},

  init: function () {
    return App.initWeb3();
  },

  initWeb3: function () {

    // Is there an injected web3 instance?
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
    } else {
      // If no injected web3 instance is detected, fall back to Ganache
      App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
    }
    web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);

    return App.initContract();
  },

  initContract: function () {

    $.getJSON('CryptoSportsToken.json', function (data) {
      // Get the necessary contract artifact file and instantiate it with truffle-contract
      var CryptoSportsTokenArtifact = data;
      App.contracts.CryptoSportsToken = TruffleContract(CryptoSportsTokenArtifact);

      // Set the provider for our contract
      App.contracts.CryptoSportsToken.setProvider(App.web3Provider);

    });

    return App.createPerson();
  },
  /*
    bindEvents: function () {
      var owner = $('#owner').val();
      var name = $('#name').val();
      var price = $('#price').val();

      console.log("App: \n");      
      console.log(App);
      console.log("App.contracts: \n");      
      console.log(App.contracts);

      console.log(owner + " " + name + " " + price)

      //createPromoPerson(address _owner, string _name, uint256 _price)
      $(document).on('click', '.btn-create', App.createPromoPerson(owner, name, price));
    },
  */
  createPerson: function () {

    console.log("lolonator")
    var cryptosportInstance;

    //##########
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-create', function () {
      var owner = $('#owner').val();
      var name = $('#name').val();
      var price = $('#price').val();

      console.log(owner + " " + name + " " + price)

      App.contracts.CryptoSportsToken.deployed().then(function (instance) {
        cryptosportInstance = instance;

        console.log(cryptosportInstance)

        return cryptosportInstance.createPromoPerson(owner, name, price).call();
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      })
    });
  },
};

$(function () {
  $(window).load(function () {
    App.init();
  });
});
```

Within my frontend I have a button that should trigger the creation of a new person:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Sports Person</h1>
    <label for="owner" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Owner Address: </label>
    <input id="owner" type="text" />
    <br/>

    <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name: </label>
    <input id="name" type="text" />
    <br/>

    <label for="price" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Price: </label>
    <input id="price" type="text" />
    <br/>

    <button class="btn btn-default .btn-create" type="button" data-id="0">Create</button>
  </div>
```

When I press the button I basically get no result. No `console.log` gets triggered.

See below my console.log from chrome:

[image]

Any suggestions why?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Are you getting at least a `lolonator` ?

Comment: @Frederik.L Yes I  get `lolonator` ;). However, when I press the button `create` nothing gets triggered. I just updated my question with a picture of my chrome console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in one of your Create button classes in your HTML. Instead of:

```
<button class="btn btn-default .btn-create" type="button" data-id="0">
```

it should read:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-create" type="button" data-id="0">
```

This is because `.btn-create` in `$(document).on('click', '.btn-create', function () {` is actually a CSS class selector.